if clause in JS - multiple values separated by comma
Why does the following evaluate to true?
if(false, true) {
  console.log("this is true");
}

the output is this is true with eslint saying Unexpected use of comma operator

What do you expect the output to be?  Do you know about the comma operator?   It's a strange use, so no doubt only for educational purposes.  Did you look up the comma operator?  Why does it do this? Because that's how it works.

The comma operator documentation explains how it works.

if (false, true) is equivalent to if (true). The value of the comma operator is its second operand.
